# How to add text inside a jquery Knob?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-knob

This is my code where i am using `data-prepend="abc"` inside the input tag but it is not working. How can I add text inside the knob above percentage value?

```
<div class=" myknob2">
  <input type="text" value="33.33" class="dial2" data-thickness=".2" data-width="130" data-bgColor="#13430D">
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $(".dial2").knob({
        'format': function (value) {
          return value + '%';
        }
      });

      $('.dial2').trigger('configure', {
        "min": 0,
        "max": 100,
        "fgColor": "#228B22",
        "skin": "tron",
        "cursor": false,
        "inputColor": "#228B22"
      });
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/a/wittybrains.com/file/d/0B1PjcJqxgMlmQUNlMU9QcGEwRnRFS3BwdUVEY2pUWFNuSHBF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is the page i am designing

Comment: Avoid linking pages where we need to ask for access permission.
Copy your page and reproduce the issue on a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or similar, if you don't want to put all the code inside the question itself.

Comment: link is sharable now.

Comment: have you resolved this issue? are you interested to achieve this with any other alternate plugins?

Comment: No.The issue have not been resolved. if there is another plugins by which the issue can be resolve.please let me know.

Comment: I have updated the alternate way in the below answer, had you seen that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I have achieved this using jQuery [**roundSlider**](http://roundsliderui.com/) plugin. Check the below demo:

### [**`DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/1119/)

Hope this helps you..